# Div extra to close fancy box with rails 3.1

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, fancybox

I have a div with a rails 3.1 partial and a link to open the partial in fancybox:

```
<div id="content">

<%= link_to "Terms of Service", "#terms-use", :class =>"terms-use" %>.

<%= render :partial => "pages/terms" %>

</div>
```

inside the div has a partial with **id terms-use**

The link generated by **link_to** method is:

```
<a class="terms-use" href="#terms-use">Terms of Service</a>
```

This is a fancybox javascript that I have:

```
$(function() {
 $("a.terms-use").fancybox({
     'titlePosition'          : 'inside',
    'transitionIn'           : 'none',
    'transitionOut'         : 'none',
     'overlayOpacity'    : '0',
     'autoDimensions'   : false,
     'width' : 610,
     'height' : 130,
     'centerOnScroll' : true, 
  });
  });
```

My fancy box working fine when I open it. But the problem is that when I **close** the fancy box create into my **parent content** div a new white or blank div with same heigh that fancy box. Then my parent div content is extended in that height. Its mean adds to the height of content div the heigh of fancybox. The position of this white blank div is relative.

**How I can fix this?**

Comment: I am assuming that you are using fancybox v1.3.4 ... and the #terms-use is a hidden div within your html rendered document that you acces with an anchor with class="terms-use", is that correct?

Comment: Is correct :D. I have edited the post for you can see the link generated. I am using this gem https://github.com/hecticjeff/fancybox-rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug (and a workaround) with fancybox v1.3.x described [here](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/fab7b6d81a173b33/).

Also make sure that your `<div>` with the terms of use content, is hidden with the following structure:

```
<div style="display:none;">
 <div id="terms-use">..content..</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, this fix working fine :D I have create other post because in opera the scroll vertical dont working fine for me. If I click in bar scroll in opera dont doing scroll if I scroll with mouse yes working fine